# spring tablib is not allowing placeholder and required attributes inside input tag, even though I used spring mvc 4.3.2

Tags: spring-mvc

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/SignUpPage.jsp (line: 70, column: 6) Attribute placeholder invalid for tag input according to TLD

The above exception is thrown in jsp.

spring tablib is not allowing placeholder and required attributes inside input tag, even though I used spring mvc 4.3.2

Comment: <frm:input path="name" placeholder="Name" cssClass="form-control"
       required="required" />

Comment: this is my input tag